# How to extract match pattern only using regex without other tools

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression that after seeing `"aaa"` code, this regex should print only 6-digit code, not entire line.  There is only one 6-digit code in a line, and it is after `"aaa"`.

I can't use `sed`, `awk`, `grep` ... etc. My application only accepts regex.

Examples:

```
x aaa    y z    123456          returns  123456

aaa  x  654321   y z            returns  654321
```

I tried this regex with backreference, not sure how not to repeat `[\d]{6}` though

```
(.*)(aaa)(.*)[\d]{6}((?(2)[\d]{6}|.+)
```

but it prints the entire line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is only one 6-digit code in a line... can't you than just go "\d{6}" ?

Comment: 'x 123456 y'.match(/\b\d{6}\b/); // ["123456"]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
aaa.+?(\d{6})
```

and then returning only the first group (with `\1`)

You could also use backreference with a different regex:

```
(?<=aaa.+?)\d{6}
```

this means that you want the first 6 digits after aaa and any other character. Unfortunately many languages don't support variable length backreferences, so I'd go with the first one

Comment: Can't see the site, would you please put it on rubular?

Comment: If you are talking about the second regex, the problem is that, as I said in the answer, many languages don't support variable length lookbehinds, thus the first grouping option is the only one working, you must output only the `\1` group

Comment: Hmm.. May be your right about variable length lookbehinds. Even rubular seems to flag it as an invalid regex. First expression seems fine though.

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem, I often need variable length lookbehinds and often have to use this workaround :\

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I understand now.

Comment: If this answer your question, would you please mark it as an answer? If you have found another solution, would you please post it? many thanks

Comment: Your first regex is not a workaround, it's the correct solution.  If you find yourself needing variable-length lookbehind a lot, you're doing something wrong.  Lookbehind should never be the first tool you reach for.

Comment: Saying workaround I mean 'I match the whole string and I handle a group instead of matching only the part I\'m interested in'.. :)